# Request timeout handling c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to know how to catch and **recognize** timeout error in comparison to other WebException errors. *Request timeout is set to "1" to make environment to be able to catch the exception. I just need to know how to recognize it.* (i.e. default working value = 60000). Here is my code:

```
// some code here
request.Timeout = 1;
// some code here

catch (WebException wex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(wex);
                try
                {
                    response_code = ((int)((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode);
                    State_show.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    if (response_code == 404)
                    {
                        State_show.Text = "Error 404. Retrying the request";
                        request_1();
                    }
                    if (response_code != 400 || response_code != 503 || response_code != 404)
                    {
                        State_show.Text = "Error " + response_code + ". Please try again";
                        FlashWindow.Flash(this);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc);
                    MessageBox.Show("Check internet connection");
                }
            }
```

So it catches good if I received bad http status code. But it throws additional exception if response has timed out. The simplest way is to get

```
string wex_modified = wex.ToString();
If (wex_modified.contains("Timeout"))
{
      // some handling here
}
```

But I don't really like it. I tried to use wex.GetType() and other available functions, but without success.

Is there any other way to recognize the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebException.Status` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `WebExceptionStatus` [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). One of the enumeration values is `Timeout`.

```
if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
{
   // We have a timeout!
}
```

Comment: It helps with some changes:
The code above throws an error that `==` can't be applied between `HttpStatusCode and WebExceptionStatus`

but `wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout` works awesome.
Thanks a lot!